# Matlab: animating the plot and fft

Tags: matlab, animation, plot, fft

I am currently working on a project that:
plot the data -> take fft -> apply filter -> inverse fft -> plot out the result.

The codes are already written out. However, because we are doing this for presentation, our audience would like to see some "dynamics" or animation with the matlab.

Therefore, I am wondering if we could have any idea to facilitate this animation in matlab?

```
fileID = fopen('data.txt');
dataRead = textscan(fileID,'%f %f %f');
Fs=1000;
Time=dataCol(:,1);
Data=dataCol(:,2);
figure; plot(Time,Data);
frequency=(linspace(-0.5,0.5,length(Data))*Fs);
F=fftshift(fft(Data));
figure; plot(frequency,abs(F));  %plot the magnitude frequency spectrum; 

%now apply filter;
mask=zeros(1, length(F));
mask(length(F)/2-2 : length(F)/2+2)=1;
New_F=mask.*F;

%show the frequency spectrum after apply the filter.
figure, plot(frequency, abs(New_F));

% do ifft;
new_data=ifftshift(ifft(New_F));
plot (Time, new_data);
```

Comment: You could write the plots as frames in an animated gif.

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Just google 'matlab animated gif' or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Are the following any helpful to you?

You can do `uiopen()` to interactively open file and get the filename. It will open a standard fileopen dialog box with folder locations. That will add some visual stuff in there. Also using `inputdlg("Plese enter bla bla bla")` will help you to get data using a text box. You can get Fs, Time, and Data from that. Also, once you proess the everything, display `msgbox("All done!")` to let users know that it's done.

The other option will be simply design a GUI window where right half will display your plots and left-half will have all the text boxes to capture file name, data, etc. MATLAB GUI builder should be able to help you construct that in 5-6 minutes.